# Two queries on a shared foreign table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a database set up as follows:

```
+--------+      +---------+
| Person | 1:1  | Company |
|        +----->+         |
|        |      |         |
+--------+      +---------+
|                         |
|       +--------+        |
|1:M    | Assets |     1:M|
+------>+        +<-------+
        |        |
        +--------+
```

Where a `Person` has a `Company`, but both a `Person` and a `Person's Company` can have `Assets`

How would I structure a kind of query, that for instance, looks for:

- People whose assets are `< 5000`, `AND`
- People whose Companies have assets that are `> 5000`

Comment: Sample data would bee very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
select people.* from people 
inner join assets on assets.people_id = people.people_id 
where assets.assets > 5000 
UNION
select company.* from company
inner join assets on assets.company_id = company.company_id
where assets.assets> 5000
```

This is uses a union of two queries.

However without a sample data size or how the tables look, we're completely just spit balling here.

Comment: This won't work unless `people` and `company` have the same number and types of fields.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess you could do something like this:

```
select a.person_id, sum(a.assets)
from assets a
group by a.person_id
having sum(assets) < 500

select c.person_id, sum(a.assets)
from assets a join
     companies c
     on a.company_id = c.company_id
group by c.person_id
having sum(c.assets) > 5000;
```

You can combine these using `intersect` if you want a single list:

```
select a.person_id
from assets a
group by a.person_id
having sum(assets) < 500
intersect
select c.person_id
from assets a join
     companies c
     on a.company_id = c.company_id
group by c.person_id
having sum(c.assets) > 5000;
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple `subquery` for `companies` should do this.

```
select * from people t1
inner join assets t2 on t2.people_id = t1.people_id 
where t2.assets < 5000 or
    t2.company_id in (select company_id from companies c
        inner join assets a on a.company_id = c.company_id
        where a.assets > 5000
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

With a 1:1 relation between person and company, I'd probably make this a single table. Especially as it's hard to guarantee 1:1 consistency in a database.

With two tables, each with their own ID, you get of course the same data by joining the two tables. The data model would look something like this:

- person (person_id, common_id, first_name, last_name, ...)
- company (company_id, common_id, company_name, ...)
- assets (asset_id, person_id, company_id, amount, ...)

So join the main tables and use `IN` or `EXISTS` to look up the assets:

```
select p.*
from person p
join company c on c.common_id = p.common_id
where p.person_id in (select person_id from assets where amount < 5000)
or c.company_id in (select company_id from assets where amount > 5000);
```

With 1:1, you could of course use the same id for both tables, which would reduce this to:

- person (person_company_id, first_name, last_name, ...)
- company (person_company_id, company_name, ...)
- assets (asset_id, person_company_id, amount, asset_is_personal, ...)

And

```
select p.*
from person p
where (person_company_id) in 
(
  select person_company_id 
  from assets
  where (asset_is_personal and amount < 5000)
  or (not asset_is_personal and amount > 5000)
);
```

I like this data model with only one ID better, because it is simpler. But as mentioned, even better would be to have just one person_company table in my opinion.

If you are talking about asset *sums* and not single assets, just aggregate the assets by reference ID (i.e. use `SUM`, `GROUP BY`, and `HAVING`).